# Java Spring Boot: How do I implement a Redis Query with 2 fields as parameters?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, redis

I've seen people saying its possible like in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53121627/unable-to-get-result-from-the-redis-using-crud-repository-in-spring-boot).

But there is no implementation, only definition:

```
@Repository
public interface StudentRepository extends CrudRepository<Student, String>{
    Student findByNameAndGender(String name, Gender gender);
}
```

I've followed the structure used [here](https://kumarshivam-66534.medium.com/implementation-of-spring-boot-data-redis-for-caching-in-my-application-218d02c31191), where they have:

```
public interface UserRepository {
    void save(User user);
    Map<String,User> findAll();
    User findById(String id);
    void update(User user);
    void delete(String id);
}
```

They don't extend the Repository with `CrudRepository`:

```
extends CrudRepository<Student, String>
```

And they have the implemented separately like so:

```
@Repository
public class UserRepositoryImpl implements UserRepository {
    private RedisTemplate < String, User > redisTemplate;
    private HashOperations hashOperations; //to access Redis cache  
    
    public UserRepositoryImpl(RedisTemplate<String, User> redisTemplate) {
        this.redisTemplate = redisTemplate;
        hashOperations = redisTemplate.opsForHash();
}
@Override
public void save(User user) {
    hashOperations.put("USER", user.getId(), user);
}

...
```

So can you give me an example of an implementation of findByNameAndGender(String name, Gender gender)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented it according to the example below.

```
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true, callSuper = false)
@NoArgsConstructor
@RedisHash(value = "parameter")
public class CustomRedisParameter implements Serializable {

 private static final long serialVersionUID = 5468738363087043202L;

 @Id
 private Long id;  
 @Indexed
 private ParameterKey key;  
 @Indexed
 private Long cityId;

}
```

---

```
  public class RedisParameterService {

  private final RedisParameterRepository repository;
  
  @Autowired
  public RedisParameterService(RedisParameterRepository repository) {
    this.repository = repository;    
  }

  @Transactional
  public void save(CustomRedisParameter parameter) {
    repository.save(parameter);    
  }
}
```

---

```
    @Repository
    public interface RedisParameterRepository extends 
   CrudRepository<CustomRedisParameter, Long> { 

     Optional<CustomRedisParameter> 
      findByKeyAndCityId(ParameterKey key, Long cityId);
    }
```

Comment: Tried the above code but not get response @andrey which spring version and redis version you are using to fetch data