# Spring Boot 3.2 with Redis DB accessing data via CrudRepository findByName(string name) return empty

Tags: spring, spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis

I have setup my project with Spring boot 3.2(latest version) with Redis DB. All working fine, saving user, accessing findAll, findById which are in-build methods.
The issue is when i create a findByName method in repository, it return empty.

```
`@RedisHash("User")
public class User implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private int userId;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String password;`
```

Above is my User entity.

```
`@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Integer> {
    List<User> findByName(String name);
}`
```

I use UserService to call this repository method "List findByName(String name);" which always return empty.

I am expecting this method "List findByName(String name);" should return a User object from the redis DB. Other in-build methods like findAll and findById return the object perfectly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to get result from the Redis using Crud Repository in Spring Boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53121627/unable-to-get-result-from-the-redis-using-crud-repository-in-spring-boot)

Comment: findByName does NOT work after adding @Indexed to the "name" field.